# Possible configuration of Nginx Docker Flask website

Tags: design, architecture

I had initially posted a longer variation of the question below on the Stackoverflow site but was shut down for being too obtuse. I am a newbie at using VPS in general and wanted to try out something with a Flask website.

I want to setup a Flask webiste on DigitalOcean with some links that launch some games either backed by tornando/twisted or to other Flask websites. The architecture for the website can be shown in the following diagram:

[image: Arch]

What would be a good model to use? If I am going for the Docker solution, should I put nginx/Docker/gunicorn in one container or in separate containers?

Please, before shutting me down, if the question is too broad, could you tell me what exactyl is wrong with the question so I can rephrase it to get at the point I am making? Thanks.

Comment: It looks like the current close voters issue is that you're requesting tutorials. We don't do recommendations for resources. Your question about one container vs separate containers seems on topic to me. You've just buried it to the point no one is paying it much attention.

Comment: @CandiedOrange I removed the tutorials. Thanks again for your correction.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking at somewhere between 3-5 containers, depending on what you want to do.

#### Option 1: Container ALL THE THINGS

5 containers. Run Nginx from a container and each of the apps, including the main site. Maybe overkill.

#### Option 2: 4 containers

If your main site is just some static content that links to the other sites, and not a complex beast of its own, you can create your own docker image based off of the Nginx image that copies the static site into the container and serves it from there.

#### Option 3: Install Nginx on your VPS

Honestly, you don't get a whole lot from running Nginx in a Docker container. It can be installed and running in a few minutes. Doing the install directly saves you the overhead of running yet-another-container. If it's a static site, just   sync your files into the right directory for Nginx to serve them. If it's an actual app, you might want to containerize it. 3-4 containers here.

---

As you see, whichever route you go, I do recommend using separate containers with a reverse proxy for each of your apps. Doing so decouples your deployments. If one of them needs an upgrade, you can do it without affecting the rest of them. If one of them fails, it won't take the other ones down with it. Multiple containers are definitely the way to go.

When you have multiple containers, it can get a bit complex to get them all up and running, so it would be a good idea to look into docker-compose or write a quick shell script to bring them all up at once.

Comment: when you say a reverse proxy for each of the apps, does it mean that I have to bundle nginx with each of the containers? I have a couple more questions if you do not mind: 
(a) Will option 3 allow me to change the backend of the site to say bottle or Django? 
(b) Is option 2 more brittle in your opinion than option 3 as if I want to change the backend of the site, I will have to restart all of the containers together? 
Thanks for your answer.

Comment: No. One instance of Nginx with a proxy for each of the apps inside its config.